# Brings externally referenced resources, such as js, css and images, into a single file

Tags: gruntjs, gulp, single-page-application

Does grunt or gulp can concat all source to one file?

I want make a site that just one file.

Cannot any tool do that? How to?

**Edit:**

Please tell me why this is a bad question.

More info: Basically I need concat JS, CSS, HTML into one file by a grunt or gulp task.

Comment: You can use npm package `grunt-contrib-concat`, where you will have to specify source and destination file paths.

Comment: Thanks, is that only for js? I saw the example only has concat of js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this:

grunt-inline
Inlines img, script and link tags into the same file.
Brings externally referenced resources, such as js, css and images, into a single file.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-inline